# What is a good way to use lemma?

Tags: environments

So, I normally work in a problem proof format.

Here's what I do

```
\newenvironment{problem}{1}[Problem]
{\begin{trivlist} \item[\hskip \labelsep {\itshape #1.}]}{\end{trivlist}}
```

And then,

```
\begin{problem}{}
\end{problem}

I also have the exact same code with solution instead of problem. Sometimes I need a solution not a proof. 
And in the body I write,
\begin{proof}[Solution]{}
\end{proof}
```

And it displays solution. Now, I've come across a problem where I need to write a lemma inside the proof environment. Please help me with what to do both in the preamble and the body.

I want the output to look like :
Lemma : Statement

Similar to what happens when I enter a problem in between

```
\begin{problem}{}
\end{problem}

\begin{proof}{}
If $f(x)$ is the ordinary power series of the sequence $\{a_i\}_{i=0}^\infty$, then $f(x)/(1-x)$ is the ordinary power series of $\{\sum_{j=0}^ia_j\}_{i=0}^\infty$ i.e., the partial sums of the first sequence.
Let 
\begin{align}
f(x) &= \sum_{n\geq 0}a_nx^n \\
\intertext{Now, we multiply both sides with 1/(1-x)}\frac{1}{1-x}f(x) &= \\frac{1}{1-x}\sum_{n\geq 0}a_nx^n \notag \\
\intertext{Using it's expansion as an infinite geometric progression}\implies \frac{1}{1-x}f(x) &= \sum_{n\geq 0}1\cdot x^n\sum_{n\geq 0}a_nx^n \notag \\
&= \sum_{n\geq 0}\bigg(\sum_{i=0}^n b_i\cdot a_{n-i} \bigg)x^n &\text{where $\{b_i\}_0^\infty = 1$} \notag \\
&=\sum_{n\geq 0}\bigg(\sum_{i=0}^n a_n \bigg)x^n \notag \\
&=\sum_{n\geq 0}s_nx^n &\text{where $s_n = \sum_{i=0}^na_i$}
\end{align}
Now, if we find a generating function for the sequence $\{1/n\}_{n=1}^\infty$, we just have to divide it by $(1-x)$
\begin{align}
\intertext{Let}G(x) &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n} \notag\\
\intertext{We differentiate with respect to $x$ on both sides to get}\dfrac{dG(x)}{dx} &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x = \implies G(x) &= -\log(1-x) = \log\Big(\frac{1}{1-x}\Big) \\
\intertext{Now,}\sum_{n=1}^\infty H_nx^n &= \frac{G(x)}{1-x} \notag\\
\implies \sum_{n\geq 1}H_nx^n &= \frac{1}{1-x}\log\Big(\frac{1}{1-x}\Big)
\end{align}
\end{proof}\frac{1}{1-x}\notag \\
```

Now, I'd like everything until the first align to be under a lemma and the real proof starts after that.

Comment: Please post a compilable example, not just fragments. And consider one of the various `theorem` related packages such as `amsthm` or `thmtools` or the core command `\newtheorem`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I don't know how to use those things. Can you just tell me how to define the lemma environment using that ? I just copied the code for problem and solution from overleaf. I don't know what it means.

Comment: Your code for new environment `problem` is not correct.

Comment: @murray But, it hasn't given me any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a comprehensive example showing various "theorem-like" environments. If you typeset this you will see that, while the theorem, axiom, proposition, lemma, and corollary environments set their text in italics (that's what the `\theoremstyle{plain}` does, among other things), the definition, example, exercise, and problem environments set their text in normal upright ((that's what the `\theoremstyle{definition}` does. And remark-like environments, such as Note, use italic titles whereas the others use boldface titles (and numbering).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{plain}% default
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{axiom}[theorem]{Axiom}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{exercise}[theorem]{Exercise}
\newtheorem{problem}[theorem]{Problem}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\newtheorem{note}[theorem]{Note}

\renewcommand{\qed}{\quad\hbox{\qedsymbol}}% run-in QED

\begin{document}

\section{Even and odd integers}

\begin{definition}
An integer $n$ is said to be \emph{even} when $n = 2 k$ for some integer $k$.
\end{definition}

\begin{example}
The integers $6$, $0$, and $-12$ are even, whereas $1$, $51$, and $-17$ are not.
\end{example}

\begin{problem}
Must an integer that is divisible by 4 be even?
\end{problem}

\begin{theorem}
If integer $n$ is divisible by 4, then $n$ is even.
\end{theorem}

\begin{proposition}
If integer $n$ is divisible by 4, then $n$ is even.
\end{proposition}

\begin{lemma}
If integer $n$ is divisible by 4, then $n$ is even.
\end{lemma}

\begin{proof}
Let $n$ be an integer that is divisible by 4. Then $n = 4 k$ for some integer     
$k$. But then also $n = 2(2k)$, and so $n$ is even.
\end{proof}

\begin{note}
The result above has the contrapositive that if integer $n$ is odd, then $n$ 
cannot be divisible by 4.
\end{note}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This was helpful. Can you tell me what is the difference between the way you defined problem environment and the way I did in the preamble ? (I just copied it from the Internet).

Comment: I wrote \theoremstyle{plain} and then the sentence of lemma. I'm getting an error saying 'No counter 'theorem' defined'.

Comment: @user230452 you need to read up on the syntax of `\newtheorem`. https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsthm?lang=en

Answer (score 1):

Will this do what you want? (You may also create the Problem environment similarly.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{plain}% default
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\renewcommand{\qed}{\quad\hbox{\qedsymbol}}% run-in QED

\begin{document}

\begin{lemma}
If integer $n$ is divisible by 4, then $n$ is even.
\end{lemma}

\begin{proof}
Let $n$ be an integer that is divisible by 4. Then $n = 4 k$ for some integer     
$k$. But then also $n = 2(2k)$, and so $n$ is even.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What about the code I have entered in the preamble for problem ? Is that different ? Also, what is the use of defining qed ? You didn't use it.

Comment: Are all those three statements required for defining lemma or just the third one ?

Comment: The `\theoremstyle` command is the default, as the comment notes. The `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]` causes any `\begin{theorem}`...`\end{theorem}` environment to use literally `Theorem` and, more significantly here, to restart with 1 the numbering of any theorem-like items -- including lemmas -- in each section. The `\qed` command *is* used by the `proof` environment, making the "QED" at its end to follow closely the last words/symbols of the proof rather than to be typeset flushright.

Comment: Yes, you cold define the Problem environment similarly: `\newtheorem{problem}[theorem]{Problem}`. Note that this will use the same typographical treatment of the problem's text as is used for a theorem (or lemma). That can be changed. Suggest you consult the docs for package `asthma` (search for amsthdoc.pdf).